# Display image using ImageView in ARCore

Tags: android, imageview, arcore

I am trying to display a 2D PNG image in ARCore, but nothing is being displayed.
The rendering of a 3D object works perfectly when I try to render using ModelRenderable. So there is something I am doing wrong when trying to render an image using ViewRenderable.

Here is the code pertaining to the rendering: In the below code, I get the error/warning, 'imageView' is never used.

```
ViewRenderable.builder()
                      .setView(context, R.layout.imgboard)
                      .build()
                      .thenAccept(renderable -> {
                      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) renderable.getView();
                      });
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/qbf"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example code](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables) uses:

```
.thenAccept(renderable -> testViewRenderable = renderable);
```

which is slightly different to yours, as you've added a lambda.

You likely want to remove this lambda, ending up with:

```
.thenAccept(renderable -> myRenderable = renderable);
```

You'll also need to define your `myRenderable` (which isn't an `ImageView`):

There's a minimal example in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables#create_from_android_widgets).

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. However, if I wish to fetch the image from a URI, the above method would not work, as I cannot load an image into the XML file from a URI as far as I know. Would you have any suggestions for achieving that?

Comment: Hey, I suggest you ask a new question bud! I actually haven't used it myself, I just spotted the typo :)